# Can you create a device file by yourself

Tags: linux, devices

I'm learning about Linux and Unix and I'm curious if you can create a `block` or `tty` device file without having to plug a real one in, using a command, and in a custom place other than `/dev`. Something maybe like:

```
root@linuxthing:~# mkdevicefile fakedevice
```

And then you can ls and get this:

```
fakedevice
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: what is that device file supposed to do? You can create arbitrarily many device files with `mknod`, but I doubt this helps you at all – what do you plan to "practice" on that?

Comment: Possibly related [What are some common use cases for creating block/character device files from the shell with mknod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206883/what-are-some-common-use-cases-for-creating-block-character-device-files-from-th)

Comment: what kind of device? block, char, tty, ... Or alternatively, what do you want to test?

Comment: Block or tty device.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256075/why-does-mknod-require-root-privileges